# Vitest using importActual within manual __mocks__

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, vitest

I am working on moving a lot of the redundant mocking code / factories for many tests

In many examples, we have mocks which import the actual module, but then only mock a single method of that module:

```
const navigate = vi.fn()
vi.mock('react-router-dom', async () => {
  const actual = (await vi.importActual('react-router-dom')) as {}
  return {
    ...actual,
    useNavigate: () => navigate,
  }
})
```

This is same chunk of code is re-used in many test files - and generally we are testing that a navigation occurs after a specific action completes. While this is only a single example, many other mocks follow this same pattern (i.e. rely on the module for most functionality, but only mock 1-2 functions)

I have created a `__mocks__/react-router-dom.ts` file which implements the `useNavigate` mock, however, I cannot figure out how to still preserve the original implementation for all of the other methods of `react-router-dom`

```
// __mocks__/react-router-dom.ts

import React from 'react'
import { vi } from 'vitest'

export const mockNavigate = vi.fn()
export const useNavigate = vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return mockNavigate
})

// ?? export actual implementation for all other react-router-dom functions ??
```